# Find fields that aren't used (have all nulls)

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've inherited a legacy database, and many, many fields are no longer being used. I can tell by querying on the last couple of years and seeing which fields are null, to at least get a baseline for where I might look.

Is there an elegant way to figure out which fields in the database are null for all records in a given set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(512);
SET @table = N'dbo.tablename';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + QUOTENAME(name) 
     + ' = SUM(CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),'
  FROM sys.columns
  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table)
  AND is_nullable = 1;

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + @sql + ' Total_Count = COUNT(*)
  FROM ' + @table + ';';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Any columns that come out 0 have all nulls (unless the Total_Count column also comes out 0, in which case the table is empty). Note that this query will be pretty expensive on a large table.

Comment: +1, ok so this is better than my answer, but I still like sum(case ..) to give the actual number.

Comment: @Hogan do you think `COUNT(column)` doesn't give the actual number? I only mentioned the 0s because any that return non-zero it doesn't really matter what the number is. But it is the right number; please try it.

Comment: You know what I meant "the actual number of nulls".  I stole your template and coded it in my answer. :D

Comment: Also, that is 2008 code because 2005 balks at an assignment in the `DECLARE`

Comment: @Hogan the "actual number of NULLs" is total - number in that column. That didn't seem to be what the OP is after and no I didn't know what you meant. Fixed the 2005 issue.

Comment: @Hogan your answer works for deprecated large object datatypes that `COUNT` doesn't work for. I'd add `AND is_nullable = 1` in to the query as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM table
  WHERE field IS NULL
```

or of course

```
 SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN field IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [field is null count]
        COUNT(*) as [total count]
 FROM table
```

also works and you can do it for a bunch of fields at once.

---

Stealing Aaron Bertrand's template:

```
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(512)

SET @tableName = N'dbo.tablename';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N' SUM(CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ['+name+' null count], '
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName) AND is_nullable = 1;

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + @sql + ' Total_Count = COUNT(*)
FROM ' + @tableName + ';';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I need that for every field in the table. The unused fields will have NULL values the whole way across the set.

Comment: @Caveatrob are you confusing fields (columns) with rows? What does "across the set" mean?

Comment: Ok, I added an example for that too.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the count of all records with NULL fields which you can compare to the count of all the records

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
WHERE COALESCE (Field1, Field2, etc) IS NULL
```