# Unable to count the no: of NULL cells in a column of a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `user` with column `data` which has most of the fields empty so it is basically NULL. I want to count the no: rows with data present in that column.

ONE WAY : So I thought I could count the no: NULL fields and subtracts from the total row.

ANOTHER WAY: I could directly count the occupied fields( but which i apparently don't know). So I wrote this for the 1st method....but the count it gives is 0. It is not able identify the NULL or whatever.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN data = '' THEN 1 END) AS null_count, FROM users";
$real= mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($real)) {
            echo "null Count: {$row['null_count']}". '<br />';
}
```

Comment: An empty string is not the same as `NULL`. Which is it?

Comment: @RedFilter When I view the DB using phpmyadmin I see the field as NULL i.e. written with words NULL in it. I guess it is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(data IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS null_count FROM users
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `IS NULL` since `NULL` is not equal to an empty string. It isn't even equal to `NULL`!

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN data IS_NULL THEN 1 END) AS null_count
```

Answer (score 0):

To find non-empty do it this way:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(CASE WHEN len(data) > 0 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS not_empty_or_null_count,
FROM
    users
```

If you don't want to count items with all spaces you can call trunc() on data before len()

Similar question (for SQL Server)

[Find fields that aren't used (have all nulls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403665/sql-server-2005-find-fields-that-arent-used-have-all-nulls/11403688#11403688)

Answer (score 0):

any reason why

```
select count(field) from table where field is not null;
```

won't suffice?

Comment: Because he does not want to count strings which are `''`

Comment: missed that somehow - perhaps better to store NULL than empty string?