# SQL to return list of fields containing No data

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: Select columns with NULL values only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only)
>   [Find fields that aren't used (have all nulls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403665/find-fields-that-arent-used-have-all-nulls)

I have a table with 400 feilds and 3 Bil rows  out of which 100 of them have no values/data. Can some one please give me a sample example or suggestion on how to proceed to get the list of those 100 columns which has null for all the 3 Bil rows in that table. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only